# Homebrew + Creating a package: How to move file to somewhere in the $PATH?

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to make my script available on homebrew: http://formalfriday.club/2015/01/05/creating-your-own-homebrew-tap-and-formula.html

```
class GitRedate < Formula
  desc "Change the dates of several git commits with a single command"
  homepage "https://github.com/PotatoLabs/git-redate"
  url "https://github.com/PotatoLabs/git-redate/archive/1.0.0.tar.gz"
  version "1.0.0"
  sha256 "336cf331429f2e0e030e5fe28bc00a4585dc6084b6937f0d73bc5431715a8506"

  def install
    // what do i put here to move the git-redate file so that it's loaded in the $PATH ?
  end
end
```

I need to move my `git-redate` file into one of the directories in the $PATH. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about that yourself:

```
def install
  bin.install 'package_name'
end
```

will tell brew to install `'package_name'` (in your case, I assume that's `'git-redate'`) in brew's bin folder, which should already be on the user's `$PATH`.